# How to Implement Custom ExpandedControllerActivity in Android Using Cast v3 SDK

Tags: android, xamarin.android, chromecast, google-cast

I am using Xamarin.Android to develop my current Android app. And I plan to make the application chromecast compatible (users can stream videos). To get this done I am following the tutorial at: [Google Cast Docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate). However the Xamarin Cast libraries seem to be missing the **ExpandedControllerActivity** implementation. They should reside under **Android.Gms.Cast.Framework.Media.Widget**, but I can only find **ControlButtonsContainer** and **MiniControllerFragment**.

The only option I can see is to implement a custom ExpandedControllerActivity myself. However I lack the knowledge to do so (because I couldn't even find the java implementation of the ExpandedControllerActivity). Some guidance to get this done, is very much appreciated (it doesn't have to be in C#, just plain old Java will do).

**NOTE** :- This is my first question over at StackOverflow, so if you are down-voting the question, please state the exact reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The java binding for the component [cast-framework](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/tree/master/cast-framework) at [Xamarin Google Play Services Components](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents) (v10.0.1.0 or v10.0.2.0) doesn't seem to generate the **ExpandedControllerActivity**. I have created an [issue on Github](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/58), with a suggested fix.